# Design ATM Machine with state design pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, c#-4.0, object-oriented-analysis

recently I've come across a question which is **Design an ATM Machine using State Design Pattern** an I'm new to design patterns but somehow I've completed the question and designed an ATM Machine using state design pattern in c#.

So, I just want to kindly tell me is there any optimization that can be done on this program, or this solution can be accepted. The current solution is running without any error.

Client Class which controls the state of ATM Machine.

```
public class Client
{
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        AtmMachine atmMachine = new AtmMachine();

        atmMachine.enterPinAndWithdrawMoney();
        atmMachine.ejectDebitCard();
        atmMachine.insertDebitCardState();

        atmMachine.enterPinAndWithdrawMoney();
        atmMachine.insertDebitCardState();
        atmMachine.ejectDebitCard();      

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**ATM Machine Class**

```
public class AtmMachine : IAtmMachineState
{
    private IAtmMachineState _state;
    public int _balance = 5000;
    public int _pin = 1234;
    public AtmMachine()
    {
        _state = new NoDebitCardState();
    }

    public IAtmMachineState GetMachineState()
    {
        return _state;
    }

    public void setAtmMachineState(IAtmMachineState state)
    {
        this._state = state;
    }

    public void ejectDebitCard()
    {
        _state.ejectDebitCard();        

        if(_state is HasDebitCardState)
        {
            _state = new NoDebitCardState();
            Console.WriteLine("State Changed");
            Console.WriteLine(_state.GetType().Name);
        }

    }

    public void enterPinAndWithdrawMoney()
    {       

        if(_state is HasDebitCardState)
        {
            _state.enterPinAndWithdrawMoney();
        }
    }

    public void insertDebitCardState()
    {        

        if(_state is NoDebitCardState)
        {
            _state = new HasDebitCardState();
            Console.WriteLine("State Changed");
            Console.WriteLine(_state.GetType().Name);
        }
    }
}
```

**ATM Machine Interface**

```
public interface IAtmMachineState
{
    void insertDebitCardState();
    void ejectDebitCard();
    void enterPinAndWithdrawMoney();

}
```

**Has Debit Card State**

```
class HasDebitCardState : IAtmMachineState
{
    AtmMachine atmMachine;
    public HasDebitCardState()
    {
        atmMachine = new AtmMachine();
    }
    public void ejectDebitCard()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Debit card ejected successfully");
    }

    public void enterPinAndWithdrawMoney()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Pin:");
        int pin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(atmMachine._pin==pin) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount");
            int amount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if(amount > atmMachine._balance) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Money can not be withdrawn because of low balance");
            }
            else
            {
                atmMachine._balance = atmMachine._balance - amount;
                Console.WriteLine("Please collect your cash");
                Console.WriteLine("Remaining Balance {0}", atmMachine._balance);
            }
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Pin.");
        }
    }

    public void insertDebitCardState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Debit card is already there, so can not insert debit card");
    }
}
```

**No Debit Card State**

```
class NoDebitCardState : IAtmMachineState
{

    public void ejectDebitCard()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No debit card inside atm");
    }

    public void enterPinAndWithdrawMoney()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No debit card in ATM Machine, so you can not withdraw money");
    }

    public void insertDebitCardState()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Debit Card Inserted");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rather try on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not here

Comment: ok @Selvin, I'll try this out for my future questions like this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. You might want to consider using an abstract class instead of an interface.
2. Instead of an abstract class you could also used default implementations but this will limit you in using pre defined members and state as in your abstract class.

This way you can have some standard functionality and avoid re writing the same code multiple times.

Override only the functionality that changes per state.

You can also easily extend by calling the base implementation of the abstract class as well as the extra logic in each state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll definitely try the changes suggested by you.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept helpful answers.